# Graph API image upload - permission issues

Tags: python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

I'm working with the python facebook-sdk (https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) and facing what I think is a permissions/privacy issue.

When I upload an image through the api, via the put_photo() method,

```
facebook.put_photo(image = img, message = "Test photo upload", privacy = "EVERYONE")
// {u'id': u'397835817076216'}
```

The image uploads fine, but even though its visibility is shown as "Public", it is only visible to the page administration.

[image: API upload]

However, if I upload the same image manually, its visible to everyone.

[image: Manual upload]

I would like the api upload to be visible to everyone, as intended(by the privacy parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. It was a stupid mistake on my end - result of many nights spent in front of the machine.